# How to provide swagger annotation for MultipartFormDataInput in RestEasy with Quarkus

Tags: java, swagger, resteasy, openapi, quarkus

while working on Quarkus with the RestEasy framework, I have the functionality to upload a file using `MultipartFormDataInput`. This functionality is working as expected, but I am unable to provide proper open API annotation for swagger UI. I have tried multiple options and combinations, but it did not bear fruit. Please help me. I provide below the sample code.

```
@Operation(summary = "Upload a single file", description = "Upload a single file")
    @APIResponses({
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Upload file successfully"),
            @APIResponse(name = "500", responseCode = "500", description = "Internal service error") })
    @RequestBody(content = @Content(
            mediaType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA,
            schema = @Schema(type = SchemaType.STRING, format = "binary"),
            encoding = @Encoding(name = "attachment", contentType = "application/octet-stream")))
    @POST
    @Path("/singleFile")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response handleFileUpload(@MultipartForm MultipartFormDataInput input) {
        String fileName = null;

        Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
        // Get file data to save
        List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("attachment");
        for (InputPart inputPart : inputParts) {
            try {
                MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = inputPart.getHeaders();
                fileName = getFileName(header);
                InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
                File customDir = new File(UPLOAD_DIR);
                if (!customDir.exists()) {
                    customDir.mkdir();
                }
                fileName = customDir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + fileName;
                Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), bytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
                return Response.status(200).entity("Uploaded file name : " + fileName).build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity("Uploaded file name : " + fileName).build();
    }
```

I have also referred to the following links.

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Open-Source-Tools/How-to-swagger-annotate-multipart-form-data-with-resteasy/td-p/178776

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3050

I am able to generate swagger UI if I create a separate class called `MultipartBody` with `@Schema(type = SchemaType.STRING, format = "binary") and @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)` annotation. But my requirement is to use only `MultipartFormDataInput`.

Comment: Do you think this question could be helpful?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950791/swagger-ui-doesnt-support-uploading-a-file-properly-for-resteasy

Comment: I have already tried, but it did not work for the latest version.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that @Sambit

Answer (score 5):

You were almost there :) Just use a dedicated class in your RequestBody/Schema and tell OpenAPI ignore the params of your method.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@RequestBody(content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA,
    schema = @Schema(implementation = MultipartBody.class))
)
@Operation(operationId = "uploadFile")
public Response uploadFile(@Parameter(hidden = true) MultipartFormDataInput input) {
//... your logic here
}
```

Two things to note: `@Parameter(hidden = true)` tells Smallrye OpenAPI to not consider your `MultipartFormDataInput` when generating Schema model. Then you need to tell describe the schema explicitly, using `@RequestBody`, where `MultipartBody` is a class that describes all your input params(you can add more params there if you want to for example pass other props along with the file payload)

```
public class MultipartBody {

    @FormParam("file")
    @Schema(type = SchemaType.STRING, format = "binary", description = "file data")
    public String file;


    @FormParam("fileName")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String fileName;
}
```

Just make sure that the `@FormParam` annotated fields in the `MultipartBody` match the ,,parts" that you expect to find in your `MultipartFormDataInput` - e.g. in your case the file attribute should have `@FormParam("attachment")`